# Blur/Focus listener on AbstractField (vaadin)

Tags: vaadin7

I am creating an AutoCompleteField extending AbstractField class.

> public class AutoCompleteField extends AbstractField{
>
> public AutoCompleteField()
>       {
>
> super();
>
> }
>
> }

I want to add a BlurListener on this.
I read the docs and it didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method to your class:

```
public void addBlurListener(BlurListener blurListener) {
  addListener(BlurEvent.class, blurListener, "blur");
}
```

Then to use it:

```
autoCompleteField.addBlurListener(() -> {
  // Do something on blur.
});
```